# R using readline and locator at the same time

Tags: r, selection, readline

I would like to have in my program the option to either click on a selection or type a selection. I have coded my program to be able to get the selection using the locator() function in conjunction with the plot() and text() commands, but I would like to be able to let the user type in their selection in the R console using readline(). However, since both readline() and locator() freeze the program until a selection has been made, I cannot think of a way to make it so that once the user has either clicked or typed the program continues. Is this possible and if so how would you do it?

Comment: Get the C code and build  Rcpp replacements that have have a timeout wrapper.

Comment: One workaround would be to require text input first.  The user could either type a selection or type "click" or "" (or whatever) if they wanted to click on a selection instead.

Comment: You should be able to do this with `Tk`, see e.g. `tkrplot`.